# Getting error while upgrade the flutter version 2.0

Tags: android, ios, flutter, web, flutter-web

I getting an error while trying to run the flutter app in a web browser.

Following is the output that I am getting while running the app :

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...

Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/wav

e-0.1.0/lib/config.dart:46:13: Error: Method not found: 'throwNullError'.
                throwNullError('custom', 'colors` or `gradients');
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/wave-0.1.0/lib/config.dart:60:13: Error: Method not found: 'throwNullError'.
                throwNullError('custom', 'durations');
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/wave-0.1.0/lib/config.dart:66:13: Error: Method not found: 'throwNullError'.
                throwNullError('custom', 'heightPercentages');
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_platform_widgets-0.60.2/lib/src/platform_app_bar.dart:209:9: Error: No named parameter with the name 'actionsForegroundColor'.
            actionsForegroundColor: data?.actionsForegroundColor,
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ../../FlutterProjects/SDK/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/nav_bar.dart:220:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
      const CupertinoNavigationBar({
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_platform_widgets-0.60.2/lib/src/platform_app_bar.dart:229:7: Error: No named parameter with the name 'actionsForegroundColor'.
          actionsForegroundColor: data?.actionsForegroundColor,
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ../../FlutterProjects/SDK/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/nav_bar.dart:220:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
      const CupertinoNavigationBar({
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_neumorphic-3.0.3/lib/src/widget/app_bar.dart:147:57: Error: No named parameter with the name 'nullOk'.
        final ScaffoldState scaffold = Scaffold.of(context, nullOk: true);
                                                            ^^^^^^
    ../../FlutterProjects/SDK/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/scaffold.dart:1930:24: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
      static ScaffoldState of(BuildContext context) {
                           ^^
    ../../FlutterProjects/SDK/flutter/packages/flutter_localizations/lib/src/material_localizations.dart:413:7: Error: Method 'replaceFirst' cannot be called on 'String?' because it is potentially null.
    Try calling using ?. instead.
        ).replaceFirst(r'$selectedRowCount', formatDecimal(selectedRowCount));
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ../../FlutterProjects/SDK/flutter/packages/flutter_localizations/lib/src/material_localizations.dart:550:7: Error: Method 'replaceFirst' cannot be called on 'String?' because it is potentially null.
    Try calling using ?. instead.
        ).replaceFirst(r'$licenseCount', formatDecimal(licenseCount));
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ../../FlutterProjects/SDK/flutter/packages/flutter_localizations/lib/src/material_localizations.dart:659:7: Error: Method 'replaceFirst' cannot be called on 'String?' because it is potentially null.
    Try calling using ?. instead.
        ).replaceFirst(r'$remainingCount', formatDecimal(remainingCount));
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/chewie-0.9.10/lib/src/chewie_player.dart:83:7: Error: No named parameter with the name 'resizeToAvoidBottomPadding'.
          resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ../../FlutterProjects/SDK/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/scaffold.dart:1437:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
      const Scaffold({
            ^^^^^^^^
    ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/chewie-0.9.10/lib/src/chewie_player.dart:276:17: Error: The method 'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'.
     - 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('../../FlutterProjects/SDK/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
    Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType'.
            context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(_ChewieControllerProvider)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    Failed to compile application.
```

Following is my flutter doctor output:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 1.26.0-2.0.pre.419, on macOS 11.1 20C69 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 1.26.0-2.0.pre.419 at /Users/sanket/Desktop/FlutterProjects/SDK/flutter
    • Framework revision 913d5933c1 (4 hours ago), 2021-01-19 22:34:03 -0800
    • Engine revision b58dbc88fc
    • Dart version 2.12.0 (build 2.12.0-240.0.dev)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/sanket/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/sanket/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode2.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.0, Build version 12A7209
    ! Xcode 12.0.0 out of date (12.0.1 is recommended).
      Download the latest version or update via the Mac App Store.
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.0

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • AOSP on IA Emulator (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86    • Android 9 (API 28) (emulator)
    • Chrome (web)                 • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 87.0.4280.141

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
Process finished with exit code 0
```

[image]

Please help me out to solve this error, My app earlier running in the browser but I don't know when it stopped working.

I tried to upgrade the flutter and dart version to solve this issue but still not working.

Comment: maybe just try running `flutter clean` then `flutter pub get`

Comment: @DrSatan1 Thanks for the response, I tried the solution still getting the same errors.

Comment: Can you show the specific line in your pubspec.yaml that defines your `environment:
  sdk: "xxx"`?

Comment: This is my environment sdk  environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

Comment: OK, that means I don't know how to solve your specific issue, but [maybe look here for some similar answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61012971/flutter-found-this-candidate-but-the-arguments-dont-match)

Comment: Ok mate no problem, Thanks for your time,

Comment: how ? anyone got the solution for this issue ? i also have same issue

Comment: Not now, I am still gettings the same problem.

Comment: For me its not working in IOS.

Comment: Did anyone found the solution for same?

Comment: @RahulMishra Till not found..

Comment: any solution by now?

Comment: Till now not getting the solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was getting the same error and I tried

```sh
flutter clean
```

and then

```
dart pub upgrade
```

for the Dependencies upgrade.

and then it started working you can just click on the Pub Upgrade in Android studio in `pubspec.yml` file of your projects.

Answer (score 1):

Good day. Please see the solution from https://github.com/i-protoss/wave/issues/30:

Add this to your pubspec.yaml

```
wave: 
 git: 
  url: git://github.com/searchy2/wave.git
```

Comment: Yes, I already tried but not working so I remove that functionality from the project and Perticular error from this library is gone but other is still there.

Answer (score -4):

I have fixed that issue buy downgraded Flutter Dart version latest to 1.22.6.

Also, In the Podfile `#platform :ios, '9.0'` to `platform :ios, '9.0'` and in Xcode go to app `Runner > Flutter > AppFrameworkInfo.plist` and change `minimumOSVersion to 9.0`.

After that run following commands in same order:

```
 1. flutter clean
 2. flutter pub get
 3. flutter run
```

All set, Project is running without any error.